# Calculate the characteristic polynomial, eigenvalue and eigenvector for this $n\times n$ matrix over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Consider the $n\times n$ matrix over $\mathbb{R}$ :

\begin{equation*}
\left( 
\begin{array}{cccccc}
1 & -1 & 0 & \cdots  & 0 & 0 \newline 
0 & 1 & -1 & \cdots  & 0 & 0 \newline 
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots  & 0 & 0 \newline  
\cdot  &  &  &  &  &  \newline 
\cdot  &  &  &  &  &  \newline  
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots  & 1 & -1 \newline 
-1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots  & 0 & 1%
\end{array}%
\right).
\end{equation*}

(a) Calculate its characteristic polynomial.

(b) Find an eigenvalue of this matrix and a corresponding
eigenvector.

(c) What is the multiplicity of your eigenvalue?

(d) Is this matrix invertible? Why?.

My try for (a) is as follows, but I think it is not right!
Also any help for b,c, and d is appreciated.

The characteristic polynomial of a matrix $A$ is given by $\det(A - \lambda I)$, where $I$ is the identity matrix and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. For the given matrix, the characteristic polynomial is

\begin{align*}
\det\left(\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
1 & -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \newline
0 & 1 & -1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \newline
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \newline
\cdot & & & & & \newline
\cdot & & & & & \newline
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & -1 \newline
-1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1%
\end{array}%
\right) - \lambda I\right) \\
= \det\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
1-\lambda & -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \newline
0 & 1-\lambda & -1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \newline
0 & 0 & 1-\lambda & \cdots & 0 & 0 \newline
\cdot & & & & & \newline
\cdot & & & & & \newline
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1-\lambda & -1 \newline
-1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1-\lambda%
\end{array}%
\right) 
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
= (1-\lambda)^{n-1} \det\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1-\lambda & -1 \newline
-1 & 1-\lambda%
\end{array}%
\right) \newline
= (1-\lambda)^{n-1} [(1-\lambda)^2 + 1].
\end{align*}

Comment: The matrix you have can be written as $A=I-P$ where $P$ is a permutation matrix. It is also quite a nice permutation, and you can find it's characteristic polynomial quite easily.

Comment: @UmeshShankar could you give more details, please

Comment: Note that $P^n =I$ so $(I-A)^n = I$. For (b) consider the vector of ones. Part (c) follows from (a) and (d) follows from (b).

Comment: It is a circulant matrix, whose eigenvalues are well known.

Answer (score 1):

Say $n\gt1.$ The characteristic polynomial is $$p_A(\lambda) =(1-\lambda) ^n-1.$$

So $\lambda =0$ is an eigenvalue, of multiplicity $1$.  An eigenvector is $\begin {pmatrix}1\\1\\\vdots \\1\end{pmatrix}.$

The determinant is $0$, since $0$ is an eigenvalue.

And $A$ is not invertible.